# Limited number of calling for a decision blackbox to compute all the solutions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reductions, turing-completeness, polynomial-time-reductions

I am trying to reduce between a solution problem and a decision version of the same problem.

The problem is the orthogonality problem. Given $2$ sets $L$ and $R$, whose size each is $n$ vectors over $\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{ 0 \right\}$, each vector with dimension $k$ (assuming $k<<n$), I want to:

- A) Find whether a pair $l\in L$ and $r \in R$ such that $l\cdot r = \overline0$ exists.
- B) Find all $l\in L$ such that there exists a $r \in R$ such that $l\cdot r = \overline0$.

Let name these problems: **DesOrt** and **FndOrt** accordingly.

It is easy to find a reduction **DesOrt** $\leq $ **FndOrt**. Simply find all pairs. If none found, return false. If at least one found, return true. That's all.

I am looking for a (turing) reduction in the other way. Ofcourse, the trivial reduction is to iterate over all $l \in L$ and call for the black box of **DesOrt** on $L^{'} =\left\{ l \right\}$ and $R^{'} = R$. But this will require $n$ calls to the blackbox. I'm looking for a more efficient approach.

Comment: If you just want to find a single solution, you can use binary search on the $L$ side.

Comment: In FndOrt, I am looking for all elements of the $L$ side that have a partner in the $R$ side. Performing a binary search won't let me find all such $l\in L$.

Comment: Suppose $k = 2$, and $L = \{l_1,\dotsc,l_n\}$ and $R = \{r_1,\dotsc,r_n\}$ such that for each $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$, the vector $l_i$ is only orthogonal to $r_i$ . Then, any correct algorithm must compute the value of $l_i \cdot r_i $. Since computing $l_i \cdot r_i$ is equivalent to the call to blackbox with $L' = \{l_i\} $ and $R' = \{r_i\}$. The problem can not be solved with less than $n$ calls to the blackbox.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, might you be willing to write that as an answer so it can be upvoted, and expand on the reasoning?  I confess I'm not following the reasoning, but it looks like an attempt at an answer....

Comment: It seems implausible to me that such a reduction exists.  The DesOrt black box gives you a boolean answer (yes or not), so it only gives you one bit of information.    The answer to FndOrt has $n$ bits of information (for each $l \in L$, answer a yes-or-no question about it), and you need $n$ calls to the black box to gather $n$ bits of information.  This is not an impossibility proof but it makes it look pretty unlikely to me.

Comment: Apologies. I am finding it difficult to formalize. The problem is the dimension $k$. Since $k<<n$, it can be exploited. I am not sure how. I think OP should also specify what other vector operations are allowed since computing the distance between two vectors is also a dot product operation: $(x-y)^T \cdot (x-y)$ and should be counted as a more powerful black-box. @D.W. please go ahead with your answer.

Comment: Computing the (hamming) distance is also allowed (as it can be reduced to orthogonality in $k$ times using orthogonality). Basically, any black box that can be reduced to (and not from) orthogonality is valid as well @Inuyasha Yagami